# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Product get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, sqlite, linq

I am trying to Query Database Context using Linq to Entities and I am getting this error:

> System.NotSupportedException: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the
> method 'AppProductAccounting.MVVM.Model.Product get_Item(Int32)'
> method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Code:

```cs
public IEnumerable<TypesOfProduct> GetType(long id)
{
    var selectedType = from t in db.TypesOfProducts
                        where t.Products.ToList()[0].ProductID == id
                        select new { t.TypeName, t.Products };

    return selectedType.ToList()
                    .Select(c => new TypesOfProduct()
                    {
                        TypeName = c.TypeName, // OK
                        Products = c.Products
                    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to get all types connected to a specific productId?

```
var selectedType = from t in db.TypesOfProducts
                   where t.Products.Any(p => p.ProductID == id)
                   select new { t.TypeName, t.Products };
```